# Using `match` together with a nested `enum` in Rust

Tags: rust, enums

Suppose I'm having an enum with some kind of nested structure. Is there a way to model this such that the Rust compiler can provide useful checks when using `match` while avoiding verbose `match` statements. For example, would something along the following lines be possible, or how could this situation be modeled better?

```rust
enum Group {
    TeamA1,
    TeamA2,
    TeamB1,
    TeamB2,
    TeamC1
}

fn is_team_a(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}
fn is_team_b(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}
fn is_team_c(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}

fn hi(group::Group) -> String {
    match group {
        is_team_a => "hi team A".to_string(),
        is_team_b => "hi team B".to_string(),
        is_team_c => "hi team C".to_string()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is having two `TeamA1` intentional? Because it's not going to compile. Anyway, what is the problem with `Group::TeamB1 | Group::TeamB2 => ` etc.?

Comment: Why not `TeamA(u8)` or something similar? If there's restrictions on team IDs, you can always handle that in a constructor function.

Comment: or `match group { g if is_team_a(g) => … }` isn't much more verbose than your suggested syntax

Comment: Although I would probably go with @tadman's solution or nested enums: `enum TeamA { A1, A2 } enum Group { TeamA(TeamA), }` then `match group { TeamA(_) => "team a", }`

Comment: Please test the code you post. `Group` is not in a `group` mod, `TeamA1` exists twice, `Bool` doesn't exist at all (you probably meant `bool`) ...

Comment: @Jmb This is going to require a wildcard, which the OP probably doesn't want.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I wouldn't make that assumption, OP states *'or how could this situation be modeled better?'*, meaning to me anything is fine as long as it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this; which one you choose is of course partially your design decision and partially dependent on the usecase.

Here's just a couple of options that come to my mind:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Group {
    TeamA1,
    TeamA2,
    TeamB1,
    TeamB2,
    TeamC1,
}

fn is_team_a(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}
fn is_team_b(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}
fn is_team_c(group: Group) -> bool {
    todo!()
}

fn hi(group: Group) -> String {
    match group {
        _ if is_team_a(group) => "hi team A".to_string(),
        _ if is_team_b(group) => "hi team B".to_string(),
        _ if is_team_c(group) => "hi team C".to_string(),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

The positive is that this code is close to your example.

The negatives, however, are:

- no guarantee that group can't be of team A and B simultaneously
- `unreachable!()` branch required because if-based matches can't be proven to be exhaustive

If this were my code, I would solve this by creating a separate `Team` enum:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Group {
    TeamA1,
    TeamA2,
    TeamB1,
    TeamB2,
    TeamC1,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Team {
    TeamA,
    TeamB,
    TeamC,
}

impl Group {
    fn get_team(self) -> Team {
        use Group::*;
        use Team::*;
        match self {
            TeamA1 | TeamA2 => TeamA,
            TeamB1 | TeamB2 => TeamB,
            TeamC1 => TeamC,
        }
    }
}

fn hi(group: Group) -> String {
    match group.get_team() {
        Team::TeamA => "hi team A".to_string(),
        Team::TeamB => "hi team B".to_string(),
        Team::TeamC => "hi team C".to_string(),
    }
}
```

Or even combine the two:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Group {
    TeamA(u32),
    TeamB(u32),
    TeamC(u32),
}

fn hi(group: Group) -> String {
    match group {
        Group::TeamA(_) => "hi team A".to_string(),
        Group::TeamB(_) => "hi team B".to_string(),
        Group::TeamC(_) => "hi team C".to_string(),
    }
}
```

Comment: I also like to `impl Display for Group` so you can just do `println!("hi {group}")` and be done with it.

Comment: @tadman Sure. But I assumed that those are just placeholders for something more complex.